# Responsive menu to push top navigation as well as page content when open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have this:

[image]

which is a responsive Bootstrap navbar that can be opened by clicking the hamburger button at the top left. As it opens it pushes the content to the right of it over and gives the illusion that the menu is coming from underneath the page. That is exactly what I want but I also want it to push the top header navigation along with the content so the whole page essentially moves to the right when the hamburger button is pressed.

I have achieved what I currently have with HTML, CSS and jQuery which can be seen below:

HTML:

```
    <header id="header" role="banner" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target=".body-content" data-target-2=".side-collapse" data-toggle="collapse-side" class="navbar-toggle pull-left">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Why doesn't iPad like navbar-toggle?!?!?! -->

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-default side-collapse in">
            <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="mainMenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
```

CSS:

```
    /*Override bootstrap class*/
.navbar-collapse {
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

ul#mainMenu {
    box-shadow: inset -5px 0px 10px #ABABAB;
    height:100%;
}

.body-content {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    transition:left .4s;
}

.side-collapse {
    top:50px;
    bottom:0;
    left:-200px;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:left .4s;
}

.side-collapse.menu-open {
    left:0;
}

.body-content.menu-open {
    left:200px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-side]');
        var sel = sideslider.attr('data-target');
        var sel2 = sideslider.attr('data-target-2');

        sideslider.click(function (event) {
            $(sel).toggleClass('menu-open');
            $(sel2).toggleClass('menu-open');
        });
    });


</script>
```

As you can see the javascript just targets the `.body-content` class and toggles the `.menu-open`. I have tried wrapping all of the page content in a div and targeting that with my javascript with the expectation that everything would move to right but nothing happened. Maybe someone knows the reason why this is happening or can suggest an alternative.

Thanks

EDIT:

It is worth mentioning that the menu items that I am showing at the side only appear when the screen shrinks to a certain size. When the page is open in a larger screen, these menu items appear in the header section at the top of the site as shown below. This is desirable which is probably making what I need a little difficult.

[image]

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGYooa

Comment: Hi @ChrisYongchu, thanks for commenting. I think this is almost what I need but I would also like to show my menu on the top of the page when the page is opened in a larger screen. I have used the `navbar-header` class to achieve this, have edited my post to include that. Is there another way apart from the `aside` that that could give me what I need?

Comment: `<aside>` isn't necessary, you can change it to a `<div>`, but I'm not sure you can accomplish what you want with *one* menu since you're wanting a menu in the `<header>` and want the *same* menu to slide the container wrapper and push everything to the side (including the header). Sorry and good luck.